# how can i put variable in pouchDb design document

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pouchdb

I am creating a design document in pouchDB like the following

```
var desingDoc = {
    _id: '_design/' + param,
    views: {
      by_name: {
        map: function (doc) {
          if (doc._id.indexOf(param + '_') == 0)
            emit(doc._id);
        }.toString()
      }
    }
  };
```

I am having the error

```
pouchdb.min.js:7 ReferenceError: param is not defined
```

1. Why is param not evaluated ?
2. How can i evaluate it ?

here is the full function

```
 function index(param) {
  var desingDoc = {
    _id: '_design/' + param,
    views: {
      by_name: {
        map: function (doc) {
          if (doc._id.indexOf(param + '_') == 0)
            emit(doc._id);
        }.toString()
      }
    }
  };

  _db.put(desingDoc).then(function () {
    console.log('success')
  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err)
    // todo handle the non saved case
  });
}
```

the _id is evaluated fine, just the map function was causing the error

Comment: The error referenced is since you haven't defined `param`. Can you post the full code?

Comment: param is the function param.

Comment: The map you're trying to insert to DB should be a value I think, which you are converting to string. For that you have invoke the function you wrote for map.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I just had the same problem and solved it like this:

```
map: "function (doc) { if (doc._id.indexOf(" + param + "_) == 0) { emit(doc._id); } }"
```

Instead of using .toString() just wrap the function in quotes.